# Nifi, how to produce via Kafka avro files with multiple records each file

Tags: json, apache-kafka, apache-nifi, avro

I created a pipeline that handles a single json file (a vector of 5890 elements, each a record) and send it via Kafka in avro format. The producer works fine, then when I read it with a consumer I get a flowfile (a avro file) each record. 5890 avro files. How can I set or merge more records in a single avro file?

I simply use a PublishKafkaRecord_0_10 1.5.0 (jsonTreeReader 1.5.0 and AvroRecordSetWriter 1.5.0) and ConsumeKafka_0_10 1.5.0 .

Comment: I recommend you to try ConsumeKafkaRecord with AvroReader (https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-kafka-1-0-nar/1.15.3/org.apache.nifi.processors.kafka.pubsub.ConsumeKafkaRecord_1_0/)

Comment: nice. Question: is the number of avro files set by the producer? I mean, if the consumer is not a nifi processor (maybe a Java application), does the person on the other side have to handle those 5890 avro files?

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem you're trying to solve. Kafka shouldn't be used for file transfers; what's wrong with having each Kafka message be one Avro event?

Comment: I've been tasked with this, I don't understand it either. I'm not sure the receiver is a skilled person and I want to see whether there's a way to put the records in fewer avro files already on the producer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, NiFi 1.5.0 is from January 2018. Please consider upgrading as this is terribly out of date. NiFi 1.15.3 is the latest as of today.

Secondly, the *Kafka_0_10 processors are geared at very old versions of Kafka - are you really using v0.10 of Kafka? You have the following processors for later Kafka versions:

- *[Kafka_1.0](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-kafka-1-0-nar/1.15.3/org.apache.nifi.processors.kafka.pubsub.ConsumeKafkaRecord_1_0/index.html) for Kafka 1.0+
- *[Kafka_2.0](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-kafka-2-0-nar/1.15.3/org.apache.nifi.processors.kafka.pubsub.ConsumeKafkaRecord_2_0/index.html) for Kafka 2.0+
- *[Kafka_2.6](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-kafka-2-6-nar/1.15.3/org.apache.nifi.processors.kafka.pubsub.ConsumeKafkaRecord_2_6/index.html) for Kafka 2.6+.

It would be useful if you provide examples of your input and desired output and what you are actually trying to achieve.

If you are looking to consume those message in NiFi and you want a single FlowFile with many messages, you should use [ConsumeKafkaRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-kafka-2-6-nar/1.15.3/org.apache.nifi.processors.kafka.pubsub.ConsumeKafkaRecord_2_6/index.html) rather than ConsumeKafka. This will let you control how many records you'd like to see per 'file'.

If your consumer is not NiFi, then either they need to merge on their end, or you need to bundle all your records into one larger message when producing. However, this is not really the point of Kafka as it's not geared towards large messages/files.

Comment: 'or you need to bundle all your records into one larger message when producing". This is exactly what I'm talking about. As to why we are using Kafka for this, I don't see the point either, but this is what my client wants.

Comment: @RiccardoLamera Instead of using PublishKafkaRecord, just use PublishKafka and send the entire FF as one message